# 'assembleDebug' Task not Found While Running From Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am new to Android development and trying to setup Jenkins to automate build generation on my mac machine. When I run the Jenkins build it is not generating any apk at jenkins workspace. I am gradle wrapper and 'gradlew assembleDebug' command but it give error that " 'assembleDebug' Task not found in root project". I tried 'gradlew tasks' to view all available tasks and it does not list any android specific tasks.

When I open the same project using Android Studio, it listed all tasks properly (including assembleDebug).

What could be potential issue! is it Android sdk path or gradle plugin in Jenkins environment causing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post the path you run "assembleDebug" command

Comment: I am using <JENKINS_WORKSPACE>/SourceCode/gradlew assembleDebug. You can find my project structure at "https://github.com/Tarunshrma/PopularMovies"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your module Gradle to this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tarunsmac.moviesapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug{
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

and try

Comment: Appreciate your help sanemars! I don't have access to my build machine, I will try it and update it. One thing I need to clear, the inner gradle file (PopularMovies/SourceCode/app/build.gradle) content to be replaced in outer gradle file as well. Am I correct ?

Comment: you can declare variable in project gradle and use it in module gradle.project gradle can not directly replace module gradle content.

Comment: Thanks again for the help sanemars, yup that worked for me. I made the change in project structure and keep the gradle file at root of project itself.

Comment: Wich file I should edit to make this change? Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

If you're landing here while searching for this error in Android Studio:
This error can also occur if one of the `build.gradle` files were updated via external means such as `GIT`. Android Studio may think it's in SYNC even if it isn't. Check that you have the correct build tools for the version you are compiling and then try the solution below:

**Try clicking the `Sync Project with Gradle Files`**

Answer (score 10):

I fixed the "task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project" error by adding an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME` was the answer for me. Specifically, Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Environment variables -> Name: ANDROID_HOME, Value: Android SDK directory

Answer (score 5):

Today, I faced this error. I started facing this error when I updated my code with SVN branch. What I did i just invalidate cache/restart Android studio, Everything got back and started working. This fixed in my case.

Comment: And how to do this

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with gradle and I solved it in very easy way
just create new project:
flutter create tempproject
go the the tempproject folder and copy "android" folder and "build" folder
then paste and replace onto your old project.
you may run:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
and it works like magic.
this way I always upgrade my projects and solve gradle problems in 2 minutes

Comment: You don't have to do all this , just delete the Android folder from your project and then run ' flutter create . '

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have below lines in your app level gradle file and it will work

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ANDROID_HOME` was missing, as I was building on a fresh ubuntu machine.

But to add it I had to install Android SDK
Follow steps from here

```
https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/install-android-sdk-manager-linux-ubuntu-16-04/
```

Download required package

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-25" "build-tools;24.0.2" 

Accept all licenses
```

then try to run assembleDebug